# Using Fedex API with Power Query to post an XML Track Request

Tags: xml, api, xmlhttprequest, powerquery, fedex

I've spent the larger portion of a week trying to figure this thing out and still haven't done it. I'm trying to use the Track API of Fedex within MS Excel Power Query using the XML method. I've gone through all the process of getting TEST credentials and Productions credentials as well.

Thanks to @DiegoColantoni amazing feedback to other users I've managed to come up with the following code:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <TrackRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://fedex.com/ws/track/v19">
           <WebAuthenticationDetail>
                <UserCredential>
                    <Key>MYKEY</Key>
                    <Password>MYPWD</Password>
                </UserCredential>
            </WebAuthenticationDetail>
            <ClientDetail>
                <AccountNumber>MYACCOUNT</AccountNumber>
                <MeterNumber>MYMETER</MeterNumber>
            </ClientDetail>
            <TransactionDetail>
                <CustomerTransactionId>TestTest</CustomerTransactionId>
            </TransactionDetail>
            <Version>
                <ServiceId>trck</ServiceId>
                <Major>19</Major>
                <Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
                <Minor>0</Minor>
            </Version>
            <SelectionDetails>
                <PackageIdentifier>
                    <Type>TRACKING_NUMBER_OR_DOORTAG</Type>
                    <Value>785459309647</Value>
                </PackageIdentifier>
            </SelectionDetails>
        </TrackRequest>
```

I have tried this code with **Postman** and have had successful responses, however when I try it within Power Query it doesn't work. I get this message in both the test and production environments

```
>DataSource.Error: Web.Contents failed to get contents from 'https://ws.fedex.com/xml' (500): Internal Server Error
Details:
    DataSourceKind=Web
    DataSourcePath=https://ws.fedex.com/xml
    Url=https://ws.fedex.com/xml
 code
```

Since it has worked with Postman I think it's something to do with the request itself but I don't really understand what is wrong.

Here's the full Excel Power Query

```
let
   url = "https://ws.fedex.com:443/xml",
   Body = Text.ToBinary("
        <?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
        <TrackRequest xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns=""http://fedex.com/ws/track/v19"">
            <WebAuthenticationDetail>
                <UserCredential>
                    <Key>MYKEY</Key>
                    <Password>MYPWD</Password>
                </UserCredential>
            </WebAuthenticationDetail>
            <ClientDetail>
                <AccountNumber>MYACCT</AccountNumber>
                <MeterNumber>MYMETER</MeterNumber>
            </ClientDetail>
            <TransactionDetail>
                <CustomerTransactionId>PruebaPrueba</CustomerTransactionId>
            </TransactionDetail>
            <Version>
                <ServiceId>trck</ServiceId>
                <Major>19</Major>
                <Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
                <Minor>0</Minor>
            </Version>
            <SelectionDetails>
                <PackageIdentifier>
                    <Type>TRACKING_NUMBER_OR_DOORTAG</Type>
                    <Value>785459309647</Value>
                </PackageIdentifier>
            </SelectionDetails>
        </TrackRequest>
    "),
    Source = Web.Contents(url, [Headers=[Accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, text/plain, text/html, */*", #"Content-Type"="text/xml"], Content = Body])
in
    Source
```

Comment: I feel flattered! Thanks. Although I now feel the pressure too. Unfortunately I don't have Power Query to try your code, I can only eyeball it. From what I can see, the _new lines_ at the beginning and at the end of the body might be the reason for your query to fail. Try: _Body = Text.ToBinary("<?xml version ... </TrackRequest>"),_. Sorry, I'm not sure if this will help you, hence me posting it in a comment. Let me know if I'm not being clear and I'll write a proper answer with better formatting.

Comment: Well, @Diego you Sir, are an angel. Fedex should pay you... I did what you suggested, which was to post the whole body inline with the `Text.ToBinary` and it worked... So yes, Excel function to convert the text to binary encoded the line breaks as well, in Postman line breaks are ignored, so that's why it works there.
If you care about such things, you could post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the solution. If not, then thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FedEx XML Plain Web Services are quite specific as far as the body  of the request is concerned: empty lines at the beginning of the xml might result in a 500 response.

This is what's happening with your Excel Power Query, see the new lines before and after the actual xml. Removing them should do the trick. I.e. this should work:

```
let
   url = "https://ws.fedex.com:443/xml",
   Body = Text.ToBinary("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
        <TrackRequest xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns=""http://fedex.com/ws/track/v19"">
            <WebAuthenticationDetail>
                <UserCredential>
                    <Key>MYKEY</Key>
                    <Password>MYPWD</Password>
                </UserCredential>
            </WebAuthenticationDetail>
            <ClientDetail>
                <AccountNumber>MYACCT</AccountNumber>
                <MeterNumber>MYMETER</MeterNumber>
            </ClientDetail>
            <TransactionDetail>
                <CustomerTransactionId>PruebaPrueba</CustomerTransactionId>
            </TransactionDetail>
            <Version>
                <ServiceId>trck</ServiceId>
                <Major>19</Major>
                <Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
                <Minor>0</Minor>
            </Version>
            <SelectionDetails>
                <PackageIdentifier>
                    <Type>TRACKING_NUMBER_OR_DOORTAG</Type>
                    <Value>785459309647</Value>
                </PackageIdentifier>
            </SelectionDetails>
        </TrackRequest>"),
    Source = Web.Contents(url, [Headers=[Accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, text/plain, text/html, */*", #"Content-Type"="text/xml"], Content = Body])
in
    Source
```